# Why do I get an index error in python list?

Tags: python

I wnat to access a list of words and create tuples for all successive words. The piece of code I wrote is:

```
for i in range(len(words)):
  temp_tuple = (words[i], words[i+1])
  words_2grams.append(temp_tuple)
print(words_2grams)
```

I get the follwing error

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-707e8a14bd46> in <module>()
      1 for i in range(len(words)):
----> 2   temp_tuple = (words[i], words[i+1])
      3   words_2grams.append(temp_tuple)
      4 print(words_2grams)

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Annoyingly when I run the folowing code, it works

```
for i in range(len(words)):
  print(words[i], words[i+1])
```

the output I get is what I want:-

```
There is
is the
the program
program for
for checking
```

I have narrowed down the problem to this bit **words[i+1]**. I don't get why words[i+1] works fine in a print command but throws an index error when I am trying to add it to a tuple.

Would appreciate all help.

Thanks.

Comment: Try `for i in range(len(words)-1):`

Comment: Got indexOut for print too, it can't work, for sure ;)

Comment: What's the last number you'll get from `range(len(words))`?  What's the last index in the list? What index will `i+1` give you…?

Comment: Are you sure the code only using `print()` works? Sure, it will print the desired result, but it also will give you an `IndexError`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to stop one box before the end with `range(len(words)-1)`

```
words_2grams = []
for i in range(len(words) - 1):
    temp_tuple = (words[i], words[i + 1])
    words_2grams.append(temp_tuple)
print(words_2grams)
```

Shorter with list-comprehension

```
words_2grams = [(words[i], words[i + 1]) for i in range(len(words) - 1)]
```

Shorter with  `zip`

```
words_2grams = list(zip(words, words[1:]))

# it does tuples with element with same index given the list as arguments
print(words)      # ['There', 'is',  'the',     'program', 'for', 'checking']
print(words[1:])  # ['is',    'the', 'program', 'for',     'checking']
```

Comment: Thanks azro. It was part of an assignment on zip so was trying various ways to do it and got stuck on the first.

Comment: @rajeev you’re welcome, don’t hesitate to accept the answer now ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(len(words)):
    print(words[i], words[i+1])
```

It doesnt work for me, and it shouldnt because of the same issue you have with first code, you have lets say 3 elements and you want python to do something with 4th.

Simple fix is:

```
range(len(words)-1)
```